# AS3 Flash CC XML need to find the attribute of a node, node number unknown

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, traversal, flash-cs6

I have imported an xml-file and now I'm running into a problem that makes me feel really stupid :/

the xml-structure:

```
<xml>
 <mylist>
  <category cat=klank>
   <word aw=nk>Word</word>
   (there are 12 of these word nodes)
  </category>
 </mylist>
</xml>
```

In flash I have a var called **curWord** which is a randomly determined word from my category. I don't know which node-number it is in my xml.

I have a variable string called **curAw**. It needs to contain the aw-attribute of **curWord**.

Then I did:

```
curAw = list.category.(@cat == klank).(word == curWord).@aw
```

But it doesn't work that way. And I'm not sure what will. I've spent a good hour trying stuff and searching the web, but I'm not sure how to describe what I need to know, so I can't find anything.

As always, your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Your root node is mylist but you reference it via list (list.category...). Is that a typo?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Not a typo. I imported the xml as var list:XML = (load xml and stuff data in var)

Comment: How are you getting the randomly determined word from your category? Can't you get the attribute when you retrieve that?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet if I could, I would. I have an array with (one to three) words coming over from a different class and I fill it's total up to (3 -12) in this class randomly. It's a bit complicated.

Comment: It always is complicated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things. I think you need to quote the values of your attributes (at least I get an error in Flash CS5 if I don't). Keep an eye on the console for errors to catch this sort of thing. Also, `myList` is part of the node hierarchy so you need to reference the `category` node via that.

You may be able to do what you want without looping, but I couldn't see a way in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e60). However, you can definitely get the value you need by looping over the word nodes in the selected `category` like this:

```
var list:XML = new XML('<xml><mylist><category cat="klank"><word aw="nk">Word</word><word aw="ok">Word2</word><word aw="pk">Word3</word></category></mylist></xml>');
var curWord = 'Word';

var words:XMLList = list.mylist.category.(@cat == 'klank').word; 

// Loop over the word nodes from the selected category
for each(var word:XML in words) 
{
        // Find the node with value matching curWord
    if (word.text() == curWord) {
        trace(word.@aw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about my code: I often simplify a long piece if I have to ask a question here. But I realise that can be quite annoying for people who need all possible information to help solve a problem.

Comment: Anyway, the piece I was looking for but couldn't find bloody anywhere was woord.text(). You have helped me immensely and possibly made my weekend, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Without looping:

```
list.mylist.category.(@cat == "klank").word.(text()==curWord).@aw
```